# Cannot login the new user I created, showing Permission denied (publickey) without asking for password

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, login, password

I created a new user in my EC2 using:

```
sudo adduser test
```

I can add it to sudo using "usermod -aG sudo test" and verify it using "groups test", and I can "su - test" to switch to test.

However, when I tried to login this user from another host(my local MAC terminal) using:

```
ssh test@EC2_IP
```

it showed permission denied without even asking me password. ssh -v test@EC_IP shows the following log:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
......
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/XXX/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/XXX/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

In fact, I can login a user of another host. ssh -v another@another_host
showed almost the same log except two lines:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
....
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

for what reason I cannot "ssh test@EC2_IP"? why the system does not check:
"debug1: Next authentication method: password"?

Comment: Do you have `PasswordAuthentication` enabled on both the client and server side?

Comment: If not, share your EC2's /etc/ssh/sshd_config file because it seems to be a misconfiguration in there

Comment: muclux and  XiR_. PasswordAuthentication is no in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. I changed it to yes and then "service sshd reload", it now works!. Thanks. note the EC2 to be logged in is new launched, which I did not change anything. looks like amazon's EC2 set PasswordAuthentication as no by default?