# How to set "PasswordAuthentication" as yes through automation

Tags: 14.04

In Ubuntu 16.4 EC2, PasswordAuthentication is no by default in virtually launched machine. It is not convenient, because I want to add new users and allow them to login with password. I want this manual activity to get automated using bash script or commands.

My Reference Question: [Cannot login the new user I created, showing Permission denied (publickey) without asking for password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987335/cannot-login-the-new-user-i-created-showing-permission-denied-publickey-witho)

Right now I manually change PasswordAuthentication as yes and then "service sshd reload".

Comment: You only need to do it once... Or do you have several servers? Even then, copying the script over and running it will probably take just as much effort...

Comment: only once. I want to add a new user and set PasswordAuthentication is as yes and then install software as that user instead of ubuntu using terraform.

Comment: Have you tired creating another user and connecting that user over ssh ?

Comment: ran: what do you mean? I want to add a new user (any user other than root and ubuntu) and set PasswordAuthentication is as yes and then install software as that user instead of ubuntu using terraform.

Answer (score 6):

The following commands works:

Save the following as script file, something like example.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# sudo sed -i "/^[^#]*PasswordAuthentication[[:space:]]no/c\PasswordAuthentication yes" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# sudo service sshd restart
```

Run the script after the above commands are saved in script.

```
# sudo ./example.sh
```